# Using MVT Style specification to style MVT layer in deck.gl

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl

I'm working on implementing an [MVT/PBF server](https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D.pbf) on a [deck.gl map](https://deck.gl) and trying to find a way to implement the [accompanying style JSON](https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/resources/styles), i.e. [Mapbox GL JS Style Specification file](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/root/) for this MVT/PBF server.

I notice there is no `style` prop for the [deck.gl MVT layer](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/mvt-layer). I could proceed with use the `renderSubLayers` prop to manually parse the style layer and match up the feature types and styles, but it would be tricky to implement the entire specification including max/min zoom visibility, filtering, text-halos etc.

Hoping someone has a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found [MapLibreGL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/maplibre-gl), this is the fork of MapBoxGL before the repository was made private and it does accommodate Mapbox Vector Tile style format for vector tiles.

MapLibreGL is a WebGL based library for creating map visualisations. A cool feature of these WebGL based libraries is that it's possible use layers from other WebGL based libraries. For example, a deck.gl or mapbox layer can be used on a MapLibreGl map.

Answer (score 0):

deck.gl does not implement the Mapbox style spec. In their words (from the [git discussion](https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/discussions/6892) intiated by @Edwin):

> There have been discussions around this feature, but we don't have a
> timeline. There will need to be new layers written. Committing to
> support an evolving spec like this is also a lot of future maintenance
> work.